# Using @staticmethod on python to pass parameter between tests

Tags: python, pytest, global

Want to know if my coding way is really pythonic

I have 2 tests (2 different files).
POST test create some list of strings
GET test should verify this list.

Solution: in file helper:

```
import string
import random
class DCB_DATA:
    dcb = []

    @staticmethod
    def generate_dcb_list(str_length, list_count):
        alpha = string.ascii_lowercase
        num = string.digits
        dcb_list = []

        for i in range(list_count):
            dcb_list.append(''.join(random.choice(alpha + num) for _ in range(str_length)))

        return dcb_list
```

POSt test:

```
@pytest.mark.order(51)
def test_post_dcb_device(self, templates, set_token):

    body = DCB_DATA.dcb = DCB_DATA.generate_dcb_list(5, 3)
```

GET test:

```
for i in range(3):
    assert DCB_DATA.dcb[i] in response.json()
```

This way is working, but is it really pythonic correct?

Comment: You're technically using static methods in (a) way they are intended. I don't see why you wouldn't just set the dcb with the static method rather than setting it manually tho. i.e. `DCB_DATA.dcb = dcb_list` and `return DCB_DATA.dcb`

Comment: Thanks, got you and updated:
import string
import random
class DCB_DATA:
    dcb = []

    @staticmethod
    def generate_dcb_list(str_length, list_count):
        alpha = string.ascii_lowercase
        num = string.digits

        for i in range(list_count):
            DCB_DATA.dcb.append(''.join(random.choice(alpha + num) for _ in range(str_length)))

        return DCB_DATA.dcb